# Select mysql column (which is array) where other column is defined,:- and insert it into php variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a two columns in database:- **copy** (which is array) and **bookid**. My code is;

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "select copy from book_outward WHERE bookid like 'B1'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $copyid = $row['copy'];
}
```

Database shows like this

```
+----------------+
| id copy bookid |
+----------------+
| 1  1    B1     |
| 2  2,3  B1     |
| 3  4    B1     |
| 4  2    B2     |
+----------------+
```

but it stores only last values which was entered in 'B1'. I also tried

```
$copyid[] = $row['copy'];
```

but in this case I have to change array keys manually every time.

My aim is to insert `copy into column bookid='B1'` and before it has to make sure that only UNIQUE values can be stored in database for `B1`.

**HTML :-**

```
<input type="text" name="bookid" />
<input type="text" name="copies[]" />
```

**PHP code for inserting:-**

```
$book_id = $_POST['bookid']; 
$copies = implode(',',$_POST['copies']);
$result = mysqli_query($db, "insert into book_outward(bookid,copy) values ('$book_id','$copies')");
```

Comment: what is the data type for copies in your db ?

Comment: @suresh datatype is "VARCHAR"

Comment: `bookid = 'B1'` or `bookid like '%B1%'`

Comment: Never store values as What does *copy (which is array)* means. can you Show sample data

Comment: So you can have multiple row with `bookid` as `B1` but each has to have different value in the copy column?

Comment: Sounds like you store the values in copy as csv, which should not be done. In this case learn about normalization

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: I have a **horrible idea** that what you want to do is `$copyid .= $row['copy'] . ',';` which would be a very bad idea. Check a basic Database Design Tutorial out from your library and read it

Comment: @Jens database sample is provided in question. Any solution?

Comment: @RiggsFolly database sample is provided in question. Any solution?

Comment: @Ronit as i have commented earlier *learn about normalization*. It is very bad db design to store csv values

Comment: @Ronit in your example `id 4` has `copy` of "2" but `id 2` has `copy of "2,3" - don't you said they suppose to be unique?

Comment: @DavidWinder Yes they are supposed to UNIQUE but i also written that it is for B1 only. Other bookid's can have same copy's but copy is unique for particular bookid

Comment: I gave you the solution in my previous comment if you had read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments mention it it not the best way to to it but it is possible.

You can obtain all the `copyid` data by:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "select copy from book_outward WHERE bookid like 'B1'");
$copyid = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $copyid .= $row['copy'] . ",";
}
$copyidsFromDB = explode(",",rtrim($copyid , ','));
```

After that you can check if what you got in the request are in there using [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$copies = $_POST['copies']
// if not an array use: $copies = explode(",", $_POST['copies'])
if (count(array_intersect($copies, $copyidsFromDB) == 0) 
    // insert to DB
```

Comment: thanks. Much help provide but last step "count(array_intersect)" is not working. it is not checking for duplicates values in both arrays. It will be really appreciated if intersect part also starts working.

Comment: Solved by myself by adding one line only  `$copies2 = explode(",",rtrim($copies , ','));` before _array_intersect_ Thanks code helps greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself by adding one line only

```
`$copies2 = explode(",",rtrim($copies , ','));`
```

before *`array_intersect`* Thanks code helps greatly.

Answer (score 0):

So, sounds to me like the issue is the original data DB schema has some issues.

A sql-like DB is not a great place to put 'array' style value. It already has a mechanism for doing this: a link table.

That'd save you the trouble of having to manually shuffle around your primary keys in this table. It's way easier to check and validate.

---

If you HAVE to do this via php code, for example you don't have SQL access, like in a controlled build environment, you should take advantage of 'string keys' to on your $copyid, (hint rename to $copyidmap) to group together like pieces of data and preserve key relationships.
so the following would be unique:
map->{bookId}->{copyid}->{id} // Where id is that primary table id. Obviously, validate and do your undefined array assignments.